# Servlet 3.0 API - Registering a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

i am developing an example servlet on tomcat 7.0.37 & eclipse 3.7. My current problem is to get it runnable :(

```
//...imports and so on...

@WebServlet(value="/Hello")
public class AdminServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1139419481702036147L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);

        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.write("HelloWorld");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

When I call the URL `"http://localhost:8080/{webappname}/Hello"` a window turned to "Status 404 - Resource not available". Is there anything wrong?

It is like in the most Servlet 3.0 examples :(

Comment: Are you sure the application has been deployed on the server and started ?

Comment: sure...logging-file said it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Below are some of the causes:

- Make sure your Servlet container supports Servlet 3.0. Most of them should support the,
- Make sure your web.xml has version 3.0. For web.xml version < 3.0, the annotations may not get processed.
- Make sure metadata-complete attribute is false. If it is true, the annotation may not get processed.

Comment: The question says he's using Tomcat 7, so the first cause is already taken care of.

Comment: So, in general sense, it can be the next two causes.

Answer (score 0):

Create `{webappname}.war`, put it in the `webapps` dir and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not mapping the servlet to the correct url pattern. The servlet name should be mapped to the URl pattern. But in your code it's not done.

To do it correctly using annotations please see the following.

```
@WebServlet( name="AdminServlet", displayName="Admin Servlet", urlPatterns ={"/Hello","*.do"})
public class AdminServlet
```

Comment: I installed only JDK 7

Comment: @GeorgeKrause: Make sure whether your Java_Home is pointing to that SDK and not the default JRE in your system.

Comment: It is pointing to SDK

Comment: @GeorgeKrause: Found the issue. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue: I had to remove "super().doGet();"

Comment: But how did it work without a proper url mapping?